# Custom data labels position in CPTBarPlot

Tags: ios, core-plot

I'm trying to achieve something like this using Core Plot:

[image]

I was able to draw the horizontal bars and the border but I don't know how to position the data labels.
Should I use

```
-(CPTLayer *)dataLabelForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
```

?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use annotations for this. Make each label using a `CPTTextLayer`. Set each label anchor point and position so that they stay next to the correct bar.

Comment: Thanks Eric, I didn't know about annotations. I was finally able to achieve the result in the picture. However I find placing annotation correctly to the pixel a bit challenging.